# Regex with single letter is not identifying

Tags: java, regex

I have a Regex

```
[\w\W][^\s]+
```

My intension is to identify a word

- may contain special character only
- may contain word only
- may contain special character and word
- can have single letter.
- Should not identify space or tab

Above 3 conditions are working, but my 4th condition is not working. Can anyone please help?

Comment: In case you don't know them, tools like https://regex101.com/ and https://www.debuggex.com/ are great to debug your regexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
[^\s]+
```

This should do it for you.

`\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negated class that allows any 1 or more characters other than a tab or space:

```
[^\t\p{Zs}]+
```

See [IDEONE Demo](https://ideone.com/2yeJ8X):

```
String str = "Your string here";
String rx = "[^\t\\p{Zs}]+";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You only  use** `[^\s\t\n]+`   it identify all single char to many char without (\s=space, \t=tab, \n=enter key)